# Batch waitfor action after string

Tags: batch-file

So i was playing around with Batch scripts and i found the command "waitfor".'
So i did a little bit of research on the internet and i found some parameters but i am not exactly sure what i can do with it. So i tried this:
I opened 2 cmd's, in the first one i entered "waitfor Exit" And in the other one i entered "waitfor /si Exit" So in that second one it said that the signal was succesfully sent, and in the other one it said it was received. But after that nothing happens. So am i correct that you fill in a string, and if the other prompt receives that string, it says it received it? So yes, how can i fix in a bat file if it receives that one string, it does this or that?

Comment: yes, that's all. `waitfor` can be used to synchonize Tasks between comand windows - even on different Computers (if they are in the same Network)

Comment: That does'nt work with Wi-Fi, right?

Comment: never tried - but I see no reason why not - given that both Computers are in the same Network.

Comment: TCP/IP is TCP/IP is TCP/IP. Doesn't matter if it is over cat5 or wifi.

Comment: right, @Squashman. But some Routers are set up to work with different Networks for LAN and WIFI.

Comment: By definition, a ROUTER, routes between networks.  It is designed to know the paths to hop from one network to the other.

Comment: depends on settings.I've seen strange things...

Comment: But i can't do any commands when i receive a waitfor signal?

Comment: @JeroenSteens the batch file should be waiting for the signal. Once it receives that signal it will continue to process the remaining commands in your batch file.

Answer (score 0):

`Waitfor` stops a batch and waits for the signal, when it gets it, the rest of the batch executes.

```
waitfor /si signal
other commands
```

It's best not to use reserved words out of context. `Exit` exits a running command prompt.